# Why is procmail hanging?

Tags: rhel, sendmail, procmail

I have a goofy sendmail aliases.local file set up to pass emails to procmail.  This is a set up that was working on ancient Solaris systems. Now I am running it on a RHEL6 system:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
```

So I have this /etc/mail/aliases.local file:

```
users-log: "|/usr/bin/procmail /auto/data/users/logs/.procmailrc"
```

The /auto/data/users/logs/.procmailrc looks like this:

```
# cat /auto/data/users/logs/.procmailrc
MAILDIR=/auto/data/users/logs/

:0
responselog
```

From what I understand procmail will just simply write the email to the file /auto/data/users/logs/responselog.  But for some reason I see the number of procmail processes grow.

```
# ps -ef | grep procmail  | wc -l
19
# sleep 2
# ps -ef | grep procmail  | wc -l
23
```

And that number continues to grow.  If I do strace -p I get this output:

```
# ps -ef | grep procmail 
mail      2872  2861  0 17:05 ?        00:00:00 /etc/smrsh/procmail /auto/data/users/logs/.procmailrc
...
# strace -p 2872
Process 2872 attached - interrupt to quit
fcntl(6, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=1697659298, len=0}
```

and the process just hangs there.  What's going on? Have I misconfigured procmail?

Comment: Is the responselog about 1697659298 bytes in size? May be that procmail is trying to append to a large file and getting backed up on itself.

Comment: Yes. There is suppose to be a cron job that runs to rotate the log file and keep its size down.  Once I fixed that cronjob the problem went away.  I also found that the procmail on the Solaris systems was built with diffent file locking options. On Solaris procmail -v shows `Locking strategies:     dotlocking, fcntl(), lockf()` and on linux procmail -v shows `Locking strategies: dotlocking, fcntl()`. Not sure what that means. If anyone knows please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jeff Schaller.  His comment lead to a solution to the problem.

Is the responselog about 1697659298 bytes in size? May be that procmail is trying to append to a large file and getting backed up on itself. – Jeff Schaller 20 hours ago

There is suppose to be a cron job that runs to rotate the log file and keep its size down. Once I fixed that cronjob the problem went away. I also found that the procmail on the Solaris systems was built with different file locking options. On Solaris `procmail -v` shows `Locking strategies: dotlocking, fcntl(), lockf()` and on linux `procmail -v` shows `Locking strategies: dotlocking, fcntl()`. Not sure what that means. If anyone knows please comment.

I found this link: http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/#compiling_procmail_and_choosing_locking_scheme